# Input field width and padding in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm having an issue where the width of my input element differs depending on the browser. Chrome gives an incorrect width where the with should be width+padding it is now width and the total padding is the minimum width.

HTML

```
<input type="search" name="keywords" id="ctrl_keywords_2" class="text" value="">​
```

CSS

```
input {
width: 76px;
padding-right: 52px;
padding-left: 24px;
}​
```

I've placed [an example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sqyn7/) to test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are limitations to the input type search as explained here, http://css-tricks.com/webkit-html5-search-inputs/

```
input[type=search] {    
    padding: 30px;            /* Overridden by padding: 1px; */
    font-family: Georgia;     /* Overridden by font: -webkit-small-control; */
    border: 5px solid black;  /* Overridden by border: 2px inset; */
    background: red;          /* Overridden by background-color: white; */
    line-height: 3;           /* Irrelevant, I guess */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add type="search"

```
input [type="search"]{
width: 75px;
padding-right: 52px;
padding-left: 24px; 
}​
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/Sqyn7/1/

Comment: This doesn't work. If you inspect the element the css isn't applied to it. It is just the default width of the element. Targeting the css class `input.text` works, by applying the width but doesn't apply the padding

Comment: It did work in the example you showed, but when I applied it on the actual website it didn't. I've added an exception for Chrome instead.